# How to move document from one collections to another? Mongoose, MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a TODO list, where I store uncompleted and completed items. Next, I have buttons, one to delete the item (it works) and second for checking or unchecking that item is done or not.

I don't know how to code a function to copy and delete item from array A and put it in array B.

Here is my schema and how I render my arrays:

```
var todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
var todoList = [];
var compList = [];
var Todo = mongoose.model("Todo", todoSchema);
// default route
app.get("/" , function(req, res){
    Todo.find({}, function(err, todoList){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("todo.ejs", {todoList: todoList, compList: compList});
        }
    })
});
```

Here is the code for new item:

```
app.post("/newTodo", function(req, res){
    console.log("item submited");
    var newItem = new Todo({
        name: req.body.item
    });
    Todo.create(newItem, function(err, Todo){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Inserted item: " + newItem);
        }
    })
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

Here is the code for deleting item:

```
app.get("/delete/:id", function(req, res){
    Todo.findById(req.params.id, function(err, Todo){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(req.params.id);
            Todo.remove(function(err, Todo){
                console.log("Deleted item");
                res.redirect("/");
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to enhance your todoSchema to track whether a Todo is completed or not. Add `completed: Boolean` to your todoSchema, then you will need to filter the result of Todo.find() so that uncompleted todos are returned in todoList and completed todos are placed in compList. All of this logic should go inside an `app.put` call since you are modifying a document.

By the way, your delete could be made more efficient by using `.findByIdAndRemove`, you should also use `app.delete` instead of `app.get` when deleting an entry.

(Side Note: You aren't moving a document from one mongoose collection to another. Each schema defines a single collection, since you only have one schema you are in fact storing all todo documents (completed or not) in the same Todo collection.)

Comment: Thanks man, it is great idea. I'll go try it.

Delete: I tried it before, but, it didnt work for me, so I code it like that.

Side note: Thanks to explain this, I beginner in mongo